# ODBCDataReader sometimes returns false even when rows exist

Tags: c#

My OdbcDataReader.HasRows returns FALSE only on the first read, but returns true for all other reads.

First I setup 2 ODBC readers to the same database connection.
If I get the information I need from the first read, then I go to the 2nd reader and grab more information.

```
OdbcConnection MACMIRROR = new OdbcConnection("DSN=AS400 - Mac-Mirror");  
MACMIRROR.Open();  // This line opens MacMirror database

OdbcCommand MMCmd_ConfigCode_SerialNum_PartNum = MACMIRROR.CreateCommand();  
// Get Configuration Code, Serial number and Part number command.

OdbcCommand MMCmd_TextualInfo = MACMIRROR.CreateCommand();  
// Get Textural information out of MACPAC for specified serial number.

MMCmd_ConfigCode_SerialNum_PartNum.CommandText = "SELECT GSMCFG, GSMSER, GSMPRT FROM GST001PF
 WHERE GSMSER='" + Dispenser_SN.Golden_Dispenser_Serial_Number + "'";


MMCmd_TextualInfo.CommandText = "SELECT CXCFGC, CXEXCC FROM EC140M2 WHERE CXCFGC='" + 
 This_Dispenser.CompleteDispConfigCode + "'";

OdbcDataReader DBReader = MMCmd_ConfigCode_SerialNum_PartNum.ExecuteReader();
OdbcDataReader DBReaderTextInfo =  MMCmd_TextualInfo.ExecuteReader();

// Use serial number to get config code.
  if (DBReader.Read())  
      {
          This_Dispenser.CompleteDispConfigCode = (DBReader["GSMCFG"].ToString());  
          This_Dispenser.SetAllParametersFromConfigCode();
               //Got good config code, now use config code to get textual information.

           if (DBReaderTextInfo.Read())  
              // Does not read on the first attempt only 
              //   (had rows is false here, but true on 2nd time through code)
                {
                   This_Dispenser.TexturalInformation = (DBReaderTextInfo["CXEXCC"].ToString());
                   DBReaderTextInfo.Close();
                }
      }

 DBReader.Close();
 MACMIRROR.Close();  // Close the MacMirror connection
```

Comment: This code will be vulnerable to sql injection attacks. You're talking to an AS400, though, so who knows if it even supports good parameterized queries.

Comment: @Joel, Thanks.  Will keep that in mind going forward, but out of curiosity, how would you suggest I implement that?  Also, anything I can do about my current problem?  Thanks.

Comment: Finally got this fixed.  I had to create the first ODBC reader, then delete it and create a new ODBC reader to read from the 2nd database.

Comment: I finally got this fixed.  After creating and using the first ODBC reader, I had to close and dispose it.  Then create a new ODBC reader, grab the data, then close and dispose (or NULL) that reader.

Comment: Add that as an answer, and then come back later and accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got this fixed. After creating and using the first ODBC reader, I had to close and dispose it. Then create a new ODBC reader, grab the data, then close and dispose (or NULL) that reader.